# How to specify a target package for ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr

If I call:

```
java org.antlr.Tool -o outdir sources/com/example/Java5.g
```

...with antlr-3.1.3 the parser and lexer code will be generated in the directory `outdir/sources/com/example`. But the generated classes don't have any `package` statement. I need them to life in the package `com.example`.

Is there a way to specify the target package?

Comment: On http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16185 they explain how to embed the package inside the grammar. But is there a way to specify it as command line parameter?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

ANTLR provides a header tool which allows you to include package and imports. You include this in your *.g grammar file:

```
@header {
    package org.xmlcml.cml.converters.antlr;
    import java.util.HashMap;
}
```

And you may need it in the Lexer as well:

```
@lexer::header {package org.xmlcml.cml.converters.antlr;}
```

and in case you need to add some members and code:

```
@members {
    HashMap<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //...

    private void addArrayValue(String content) {
    //... code required by snippets in the grammar

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for throwing in the bit about the members and code, even tho he didn't ask for it. +1

Answer (score 29):

An old question with a perfectly good answer, but since the comment on the question asked for a command line option (and that was what I was actually searching for when I got here), I thought I'd just chime in and say the following...

You can specifiy the package on the command line if you are using ANTLR 4.  I [checked](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Command+line+options) and it seems to not be there in version 3 so the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655920/1039947) answer is the way to go for ANTLR 3.

Here is an example:

```
java -cp antlr-4.4-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -package my.package MyGram.g4
```

See the `-package` option at [ANTLR Tool Command Line Options](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md) for more information.

Comment: The "ANTLR Tool Command Line Options" documentation requires credentials to access. Here's an open documentation of antlr4: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: ANTLR Tool Command Line Options: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md

Comment: Thanks @EFreak - I adjusted the link in the question to your suggestion

Comment: any idea why this isn't exposed in the gradle plugin?

Comment: In gradle you can append the argument to the `arguments` property of the `generateGrammarSource` task: `generateGrammarSource {arguments += ["-package", "my.package"]}`

Comment: For an Eclipse newbie... how does one find the generateGrammerSource property?

Answer (score 2):

For folks using Gradle's Antlr plugin toss this into your `build.gradle.kts`,

```
tasks {
    generateGrammarSource {
        val pkg = "com.stackoverflow.antlr"
        arguments = arguments + listOf("-package", pkg)
        outputDirectory = outputDirectory.resolve(pkg.split(".").joinToString("/"))
    }
}
```

The `outputDirectory` part might not be needed, but for whatever reason Antlr does not put generated files into the package directory layout even though you give it a package. I wonder if this is a bug [because the documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8dcc6526cfb154d688497f31cf1e0904801c6df2/doc/tool-options.md) mentions another option which makes it sound like it tries to. Either way, this works for me.

> `-Xexact-output-dir  all output goes into -o dir regardless of paths/package`

*(Also, I am on Windows and the `/` instead of `\\` seems to be working just fine.)*

Comment: Your answer really helped me. Generated sources are placed in right folder/package. I removed this line `arguments = arguments + listOf("-package", pkg)`  and added `@header { package com.stackoverflow.antlr; }` after `grammar ...` line in .g4 file.

Answer (score 0):

It may have changed in more recent versions.
I'm working on a DSL for a Savantly game service, and
I place my grammar files in subfolders.
The generated classes are in a package corresponding to the folder structure.

My plugin configuration looks like this -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${antlr.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <includes>
           <include>**/*.g4</include>
        </includes>
        <visitor>true</visitor>
        <listener>true</listener>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>antlr4</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the resulting folder structure -

[image]