# ANTLR: 'Dynamic' Test Rig idiom?

Tags: maven, antlr

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1 with a Maven project with the ANTLR Maven Plugin to generate a Lexer+Parser Java class - this works.

What I'm struggling to work out:

How can I build a test rig within the same project, such that the Lexer and Parser Class are found at development-time ?

Is there a Maven-way of specifying : build the 'generated source' stuff first (ie, Antlr-generated) THEN my 'manual' source?

Should I build a secondary Maven Project, which relies on the first project ?

Is there is a 'generic' (dynamic?) mechanism for building an ANTLR test rig class that doesn't really on Parser/Lexer class already existing ? (a 'ClassForName' JDBC-Style mechanism ?)

To Clarify the issue; here's a snippet of my Test Rig class, which is uncompilable (due to the Lexer / Parsers not having been built yet....):

```
...
    myLexer lexer = new myLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    myParser parser = new myParser(tokens);
    parser.file();
...
```

OK - after the advice below and double-checking the generated java - in fact I hadn't noticed that my Grammar file (although laid out in java package structure) did not contain a @header directive to specify a target java project for the generated classes to live in.

This was the reason that my test (or indeed my main program) was unable to see the Lexer/Parser classes. (I was simply trying to access java classes which were in a different package structure to what I had thought).

This other StackOverFlow case was the final clincher for me:

[How to specify a target package for ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655854/how-to-specify-a-target-package-for-antlr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing is to configure the antlr3-maven-plugin correctly like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>antlr</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

furthermore to put the grammar into the correct location **src/main/antlr3** plus the package name. By using this the grammer will generate the java code from it and will also make sure to compile the sources as well. I'm using [ANTLR my own in a small project you might take a look as an example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/sapm/). Also you can see an [example of a unit test which uses the generated parser](https://github.com/khmarbaise/sapm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/soebes/subversion/sapm/AccessRulesGroupGroupFromConfigFileTest.java).

Comment: Thanks for this - I just checked my pom.xml - and it has this bit set up correctly - what I'm trying to do is test my compiled Java Parser/Lexer - and to do that I have have to references to these classes before they 'exist'. (So I'm struggling with the fact that I have generated code from antlr - and a manually built test-rig which refers to those classes).

Comment: That is no problem, cause Maven will make sure that the grammar has been used to generate the parser/lexer before the real code will be compiled and the test code will be compiled based on the [life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Or may be i misunderstand your question?

Comment: I think I might have a very specific problem with my Netbeans setup or something - the IDE is insisting that my (manual/test-rig) code will not compile upon build....it sounds like in principle this should work though - I'll take a look at your github project as well - if I can get that compiled and working, maybe it'll give me the clue I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Where is the manual/test-rig folder located? src/test/java ? If it's not than your a completely wrong in basic Maven usage (unit tests have to be located into src/test/java/.

Comment: ah - that could be it....yes, I should (obviously now I think about it) treat this as a unit test, rather than a 'calling' program wrapping round the parser/lexer - I'll give that a go - thanks again.

Comment: To be more accurate this is not really a unit test but in this case it's ok to look at it as a unit test. It's of course an integration test. To be scrupulous it should be named like *IT.java and see as an integration and let it run in the integration test lifecycle phase via maven-failsafe-plugin but it's ok.

Comment: ok - I think is turning out to be a general problem with my Maven configuration - my test classes are simply not able to pick up the the required generated->compiled Lexer/Parser classes - I get an 'Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol symbol : class myLexer location mypackage' when running unit tests. (I re-wrote my test rig as 'pretend' unit test, so I can use 'mvn test' to drive it).....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21816/discussion-between-monojohnny-and-khmarbaise)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips here - It allowed me to eliminate certain cases of error - and I'll mark this as the accepted answer as well - since your answer was correct and confirmed the correct configuration of the ANTRL plugin ; the issue just turned out to be a confusion of what the generated classes's packages were. Thanks